# how can i generate csv file Cgridview datas on button click

Tags: jquery, yii

i have the following code. i want to get csv Cgridview after clicking on lang_generate button

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'post-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'columns'=>array(
    array(
    'name'=>'id',
    'value'=>'$data["id"]',
    ),
)); 
?>


 <?php           
         echo Chtml::button('Lang generate',array(            
                'id'=>'lang_generate'
));           
    ?>
```

Comment: Your `$dataProvider` already contains all values of `Cgridview`. Please correct your question cause it's have no sence.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/306/exporting-cgridview-results-to-csv-file/